# Conectar Java ao Acess (.accdb)

Tags: java, mysql, localhost

Estou tentando conecatar uma aplicação desktop que utiliza Java a um servidor. Primeiramente tentei utilizar o Acess, mas tive problema com drivers, tentei usar o UCanAccess e mais problemas, enfim, desisti, parti pro bom e velho MySQL.

Primeiramente tive muitos problemas pra passar da parte de Conexão, estourava excessão sempre no "DriverManager.getConnection()", após muito trabalhar, consegui corrigir.

No entanto, agora ao tentar inserir dados, outro erro acaba aparecendo:

[image: Erro]

Comment: Adicione o código em forma de texto, não em forma de imagem, isso atrapalha quem for te ajudar a testar e analisar o código. Leia mais no [**Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas**](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/28595)

Comment: Adicione também o erro que ocorre.

Comment: "*... outro erro acaba aparecendo*" - qual erro?